# What is the "X" part of the encoding of the r8-15 registers?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, machine-code

On [this chart](https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#Registers) it shows that both registers have the `0b010` for the register value:

[image]

What is the `X` value here? In dissassembling the following two instructions:

```
add $1, %dl
add $1, %r10b
```

I get:

```
>>> x/3bt $pc
0x401000 <_start>:                  10000000    11000010    00000001
>>> x/4bt $pc+3
0x401003 <_start+3>:    01000001    10000000    11000010    00000001
```

So, I'm guessing the `X` is the LSB in the prefix byte since the `0100` is static, correct? What does the `X` mean and what does that mean whenever one of the r8-r15 registers is used an extra byte needs to be added/prefixed in order to say that "This is register r10 not rdx" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*`X`* is a placeholder in that table you linked at the top of the page.  It applies *any* time there's a register number in machine code.  The leading bit comes from one of the fields in the REX prefix, depending on which which field this is.

That's why the leading bit is separated from the other 3 in the `0.010` bit pattern; with no REX prefix it's implicitly `0`.

In your case, it's the `.B` bit because it's modifying the `r/m` field of ModRM in `add $imm8, r/m8`.  (And because we can can see it's the low bit of the REX prefix).

[The REX prefix](https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#REX_prefix) (another section on the same page you linked) is how x86-64 added 8 new registers, and a choice of 32 or 64-bit operand-size, via a prefix without modifying the rest of the instruction encoding.  16 and 32-bit x86 machine code of course uses 3-bit fields for register numbers.

The REX prefix can provide a 4th reg-num bit for instructions like `add r8, [rcx + r9*8]` which includes 3 register numbers (MODRM.reg, MODRM.rm or SIB.base, and SIB.index).  And has the `.W` bit set for 64-bit operand size.

**The choice of *`X`* as a placeholder is slightly confusing because one of the REX fields is named `X` (the SIB.index).**  But that's *not* what they're referring to.

---

Also note that `r10l` and `r10b` are alternate names for the same register.  AMD originally used `r8-15b` ("byte") when defining AMD64.  Intel apparently invented the `r8-15l` ("low") names later (for similarity with AL/CL/DL/BL/SPL/...), but the `b` names are more popular and widespread.  [Why does Apple use R8l for the byte registers instead of R8b?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43991779/why-does-apple-use-r8l-for-the-byte-registers-instead-of-r8b)

Comment: do you think that's a typo then? Also, shouldn't it be R10B and not R10L in the table? -- `Error: bad register name %r8l'`

Comment: R10B and R10L mean the same thing.

Comment: @carl.hiass: Not a typo, I updated my answer after having a 2nd look at the page.  X in that table is a placeholder.